# What is the meaning of "unitize a vector"?

Tags: vector-spaces, computational-geometry

The expression "to unitize a vector" is often use in computational geometry. What does it mean?

Comment: I would guess normalize. But I won't pretend I do any computational geometry whatsoever.

Comment: It is lamentable that different areas of mathematics develop different terms for the same stuff. This just contributes to siloization, which has not been good for the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, it's a perversion of normalize. If $v\not = 0$, we normalize v as follows
$$w = {v\over \|v\|}.$$
Why this ugly neologism is needed is beyond me.

Comment: To me, "unitize" seems like a better term -- you are modifying the vector to make its length unity. The term "normalize" isn't very descriptive. If a vector has unit length, in what sense is it "normal" ?? If vector's length is different from 1, is it then "abnormal" ??

Comment: Normalize is used in the sense of "standardize", as you might do with a normally distributed random variable to give it zero mean and unit variance.

Comment: I'm guessing they want to distinguish it from "norm", which could have different definitions, but now they have a name conflict with the unit type, which is sort of worse than conflicting with true and false.